# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket problem

Tags: networking, server, apache2, mysql

Did anyone experience this issue?

```
root@spmmktlxcrm002:~# tail -f /var/log/upstart/mysql.log

Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
200722 11:16:11 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
200722 11:16:11 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.
200722 11:16:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log) starting as process 6213 ...
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Which Ubuntu version are you using? And why are you using root account?

Comment: You will have to provide more information. Is MySQL running?